# Java Buffered Reader Stuttering when reading byte by byte

Tags: java, android, shell, android-studio

I just programmed a little Android app that needs to read from a program output and displays it in real time. After a lot of time I finally done a simple thing that reads from a Inputstream with a Buffered Reader that is being read byte by byte. But for somehow when there is a lot of stuff being displayed it hangs at a certain state and begins Stuttering a lot. So not the whole 100 lines are displayed but like 10 first and then all the other ones after one minute. Any way to fix this? I'm running Android Studio 3 Canary preview. Code for printing stdout to Textview is attached.

```
public void stdout(final InputStream i){
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            TextView m = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            m.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(i));
            int line;
            try{
                while(true){

                    line = br.read();
                    if (line == -1)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        final StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
                        final int finalLine = line;
                        b.append(String.valueOf((char)finalLine));
                        final String t = b.toString();
                        m.post(new Runnable(){
                            @Override
                            public void run(){
                                TextView m = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
                                m.append(t.toString());

                            }
                        });

                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                m.setText("error" + e.toString());
            }
        }
    };

    new Thread(r).start();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to put all this in an asyncTask with a publishProgress method doing the actual m.append(t.toString()); ?

Comment: A new Runnable per character is insane.

Comment: Any other idea for real-time reading a process output on Android with Java??? User3793589 I'm gonna try asynchronous task..

Comment: @EJP I know but otherwise I'll miss chars as it stops at the end when no output supplied.

Comment: `line = br.read();`. You call that int a line. But you read only one char. Cumbersome. And you start a runnable for every char. Bad idea. It makes no sense to construct a StringBuilder for one char. Change to String line = br.readLine();

Comment: @greenapps then it wouldn't be real time as the readline() stops exactly one line before the output ends. So I would miss my last line of "ls /opt" command as example.

Comment: Dont understand. If you could break at br.read() returning -1 you could then break at br.readLine() returning null.

Comment: Real time? Every char? Why line by line would not be ok?

Comment: Line by line waits until the next line has been flushed before printing it. But if the last line never been flushed it would never appear. And obviously you can't force to flush buffers In Android.

Comment: ?? Can you read all lines with readLine()? What are you talking about printing? We were talking about reading from input stream.

Comment: `m.setText("error" + e.toString());`. That would crash your app. Use a runnable too.

Comment: @greenapps I need to clarify something for you :) on the one side we got the program which writes something to the inputstream but it does not sends it until it got a line.And the function br.readline() does not reads from those written stuff until there is a full line for the buffered reader. So reading byte by byte solves this problem as it does not care about what is being flushed, instead just reading directly what is written. ReadLine() does so it and normally a shell will automatically flush that last pieces